# HTML Agility Pack vs jquery

Tags: c#, html-parsing

Do you know of any extension for HTML Agility Pack, that allows querying HtmlDocument object (created by HAP) in jQuery style (instead of XPath)?

Comment: I know this question is pretty old. I came here by accident when searching for options myself :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, check http://code.google.com/p/fizzler/

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that such a library exists. You can always go the Linq to XML route though.

Comment: Ok. I picked up some XPath basics and it looks quite easy for my needs.